# Allow Node.js app to talk to a pod on a Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: node.js, azure, load-balancing, azure-load-balancer

I have a Node.js app in Azure and I want it to be able to connect/talk to a pod on a kubernetes cluster (this pod has an external IP and is a load balancer). On click of a submit button on my Node.js app, I want to be able to send bash commands to the pod on the Kubernetes cluster.

Would you know how I could connect the app to the pod? I know there is server.listen function in the index.js file, however I am not too sure how to approach the situation.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure, but you can connect the pod in a Kubernetes Cluster as you connect the Database or other services as usual in the Node.js app.

All of all, you should get the credential of the AKS through the command `az aks get-credentials` to create a tunnel with the Kubernetes Cluster. Then you can use the command [`kubectl exec`](http://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_exec/) to execute the bash shell command in the pod.

Also, you can take a look at [Executing commands in Pods using K8s API](https://blog.openshift.com/executing-commands-in-pods-using-k8s-api/), maybe it would be helpful.

Here are the examples that manage the pod in the Kubernetes CLuster pod. See [kubernetes-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kubernetes-client).